# Why are (3-methylbut-2-en-2-yl)benzene and (3-methylbut-1-en-2-yl)benzene not stereoisomeric?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, cis-trans-isomerism

[image]

My answer key says neither product exhibits stereoisomerism, but both products are substituted. Why is it that I cannot assign E/Z configuration? I thought the only time you cannot assign E/Z is when the product is either mono or unsubstituted.

Comment: Even "unsubstituted" would have hydrogens connected... It's about symmetry not no. of substituents

Comment: in an unsubstituted alkene, there would be H's on all four sides of the double bond, so when assigning priority to determine E/Z, it would be impossible because nothing has priority over anything else...everything is H. The same would be true of a monosubstituted alkene- there are to many H's to assign priority. So only things that are tri or tetra substituted can be assigned E/Z. The above products should be able to be assigned E/Z...i am just wondering why my book says they are not stereoisomeric.

Comment: Because they aren't - if you have only 2 substituents connected to 1 atom or three identical groups they can't be

Comment: Try assigning a label to each one and you will see why it is not possible.

Answer (score 3):

> I thought the only time you cannot assign E/Z is when the product is either mono or unsubstituted.

Well, you cannot assign E/Z when it doesn't make any sense.

tl;dr: When on at least one side of double bond two identical groups or atoms (e.g., Hydrogen), there's only one way to arrange substituents near double bond.

E/Z is used to explain how substituents *on different sides of double bond* located, which excludes 1,1-substituted ethylenes (which is the case with minor product on your figure).

When on one side of double bond is two identical groups, e.g., methyl (which is the case with major product) there's no E/Z isomerism too, because there's only one way to arrange substituents. You can actually think of first case as of the second, minor product has 2 identical atoms at one side of double bond.

Hope I haven't made more confusion than there was.

Also, I would suggest to play with some ball and stick models (They could be at the uni library), I think that building couple of examples and trying to rearrange them to stereoisomeric form will help with understanding stereochemistry in general.

Comment: I see what you mean. If there are two identical substituents, then it doesn't make sense to assign E/Z because there would be no way to differentiate between high priority and low priority. Thanks!